# how can I use a special keyword as my fabric function name?

Tags: python, fabric

How can I make a fabric function with reserved keywords like this?

```
def not(*args):
    ......
```

This throws a "invalid syntax" error. Is there any way to override the special keyword and use it as a function name in classic method?
I can do this with @task `alias` but all my other functions follow classic method. 
http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/tasks.html#task-decorator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks fine to me:

fabfile.py

```
from fabric.api import task

@task(alias='not')
def _not():
    print 'not called'

@task(alias='in')
def _in():
    print 'in called'

@task(alias='while')
def _while():
    print 'while called'
```

old style:

```
from fabric import state

def _not():
    print 'not called'

def _in():
    print 'in called'

def _while():
    print 'while called'

state.commands['not'] = _not
state.commands['in'] = _in
state.commands['while'] = _while
```

and to run it.

```
$ fab not while in
not called
while called
in called

Done.
```

Also. Next time add `python` to the tags, this was almost impossible to get "finded" -- haha.

Comment: Added python tag. I see that I can make this work with @task decorator, but I needed to use the classic method.

Comment: Whats the version of python and fabric that you're using?

Comment: python- 2.7.6, fabric- 1.10.2

Comment: You should really look into migrating to the new style. I did it, read through their code, but i feel dirty, feels like i should just take a shower. Im ashamed of myself.. :/

Comment: Thanks for the help with old style. moving all the tasks to the new style is currently out of scope:)