# Create a method named 'def'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way in python to override the definition of def?

Trying to create a method which will be named `def`, like this:

```
MyObject.def(arguments)
```

Comment: `def` is a keyword and cannot be used as an ordinary identifier. This is like naming a variable `if` or `import`, for example.

Comment: No, `def` is a Python keyword

Comment: `def` would be a terrible name for a function, what is it you're trying to do exactly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33158137/how-can-i-use-a-special-keyword-as-my-fabric-function-name https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968516/how-do-i-use-a-keyword-as-a-variable-name

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. `def` is a [keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords), so can't be overridden (unlike built-ins like `max` which can). Instead the convention is to add a trailing underscore:

```
class MyObject:
    def def_():
        pass
```

Although a better solution might be to expand the name: `define`

Comment: The [keyword list is part of the language spec](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords), which is binding on alternate implementations; you can't use `def` as a name (without cheesy hacks like Mad Physicist's "solution") on any conforming Python implementation.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks! I added that in.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class A:
    def x(self):
        print('hi')
    x.__name__ = 'def'

setattr(A, 'def', A.x)
delattr(A, 'x')
```

You won't be able to call the method literally:

```
>>> A().def()
...
    A().def()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But the following will work:

```
>>> getattr(A(), 'def')()
'hi'
```

This is a terrible idea. `def` is a reserved keyword. While you can use the fact that class namespaces are dictionaries with string keys, please don't.

Comment: This is possible in principle, but you should not do it, and furthermore the syntax proposed in the question will not be possible (since `def` is a reserved word): `MyObject.def(arguments)`

Comment: But how you do you use it?

Comment: @norok2: The only way to use it would be with `getattr` calls on instance of `A`. `MyObject.def(args)` wouldn't be legal.

Comment: @Fenyang. Agreed and updated

Comment: @norok2. I've added some text.